# use Jersey Library in a Android project

Tags: android, jersey

I try to implement a restful client on android via Jersey library. It works pretty well in a Java project. But when I do it in a android project, always come up an exception: could not find class "com.sun.jersey.api.client.config...." It seems that the library cannot be found even I have added it in the build path.

Comment: Where is the library file located?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Jersey currently is not ported to Android. But for example Restlet does explicitly support Android and also implements the same API (JAX-RS).

Answer (score 0):

The jar file needs to physically be located in the directory /libs in your project to be included into the distributed apk and linked to the app at runtime.