# Access ResTWebService in Android

Tags: android, web-services, rest, webservices-client

I'm developing some applications and I want to connect them to a Restful WebService. To do that I wrote this class:

```
public class TagDS {
    public TagDS(){
    }

    public boolean recordTag(Tag t){
        try{    
        String send = t.getConteudo()+"\n"+t.getId()+"\n"+t.getURL()+"\n"+t.getData()+"\n"+t.getUser();
        postService(send);
        return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void postService(String send) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

        service.path("rest").path("project").path("create").path(send).accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).post();
    }

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(
                "http://localhost:8080/pt.Android.Project.WebService").build();
    }
}
```

But when I run the application, is displayed the menssage:

```
<p>08-16 10:24:33.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main </p>
<p>08-16 10:24:33.280: E/AndroidRuntime(24149): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig</p>
```

I have all the libraries added to the project. My question is: Is it possible that libraries are not loaded when we are creating a apk?

I have tested my WebService separatly and it works normally. I thought "maby the problem was android permissions" but I searched  and I have the permission:

```
 <user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Can you help me?

Sincerely,
Rita

Comment: Did you add the required jars to the lib folder in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need jersey to access a web service from android? Not all java libraries are supported by android's version of 'java-like' virtual machine.

Comment: Hum.. I  tried to do with HttpClient but without success so I made it with the jersey. 

When I did with the HttpClient I could read but I couldn't do a post, so I gave up I wrote with jersey,

Comment: looks like jersey isn't supported:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127997/use-jersey-library-in-a-android-project

Comment: Seriously! :S I tried with HTTPClient but without success! Someone can give some tips who to do a post with httpClient.. I tried but didn't work! :S I I already saw a lot's of tuts. But they have only gets! I can show my code!

Comment: you should post another question about that and close this one.